# Getting the correct output units from the PLOMB (Lomb-scargle periodogram) function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to analyze timeseries of wheel turns that were sampled at 1 minute intervals for 10 days. *t* is a 1 x 14000 array that goes from .1666 hours to 240 hours. *analysis.timeseries.(grp).(chs)* is a 1 x 14000 array for each of my groups of interest and their specific channels that specifize activity at each minute sampled. I'm interested in collecting the maximum power and the frequency it occurs at. My problem is I'm not sure what units f is coming out in. I would like to have it return in cycles per hour and span to a maximum period of 30 hours. I tried to use the Galileo example in the documentation as a guide, but it didn't seem to work. 
Below is my code:

```
groups = {'GFF' 'GMF' 'SFF' 'SMF'};
chgroups = {chnamesGF chnamesGM chnamesSF chnamesSM};
t1 = (t * 3600); %matlab treats this as seconds so convert it  to an hour form
onehour = seconds(hours(1));
for i = 1:4
grp = groups{1,i};
chn = chgroups{1,i};
    for channel = 1:length(chn)
        chs = chn{channel,1};
        [pxx,f]= plomb(analysis.timeseries.(grp).(chs),t, 30/onehour,'normalized');
        analysis.pxx.(grp).(chs) = pxx;
        analysis.f.(grp).(chs) = f; 
        analysis.lsp.power.(grp).(chs) =   max(pxx);
        [row,col,v] = find(analysis.pxx.(grp).(chs) ==    analysis.lsp.power.(grp).(chs));  
        analysis.lsp.tau.(grp).(chs) = analysis.f.(grp).(chs)(row);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but it is hard to put a image in a comment.

Judging by this ([plomb manual matlab](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html)), 
[image]
I think that `pxx` is without dimension as for `f` is is the frequency so 1/(dimension of `t`) dimension. If your `t` is in hours I would say h^-1.

So I'd rather say try

```
[pxx,f]= plomb(analysis.timeseries.(grp).(chs),t*30.0/onehour,'normalized');
```